# How can I send a pull request using hub with the default message (without opening a text editor)?

Tags: github, go

I am using [`hub`](https://github.com/github/hub) to send a pull request from the command line like so:

```
hub pull-request -b upstream:master -h me:feature
```

When I do this, `hub` automatically opens up my terminal text editor and displays the pull request message so that I can edit it. However, 9.99 times out of 10 I am completely content with the message that `hub` chooses as the default, so I would rather just have `hub` use the default message without opening up a text editor. Is there any way to do this?

I know I could use `hub pull-request -m "message" ...`, to avoid using an editor, but that would actually be more work because I would need to retype the message. None of the other options on the [`hub` `man` page](https://github.com/github/hub/blob/master/man/hub.1.ronn#L145) seem to do this either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check how [`commands/pull_request.go#pullRequest()`](https://github.com/github/hub/blob/af9163b699b34ffa167ef99853ff2f7374d7b01a/commands/pull_request.go#L58-L79) is implemented, it doesn't seem possible to avoid the editor.

This shouldn't be very difficult to propose a patch adding a new option to this command, which would [avoid the lines](https://github.com/github/hub/blob/af9163b699b34ffa167ef99853ff2f7374d7b01a/commands/pull_request.go#L175-L182):

```
message, err := pullRequestChangesMessage(baseTracking, headTracking, fullBase, fullHead)
utils.Check(err)
editor, err = github.NewEditor("PULLREQ", "pull request", message)
utils.Check(err)
title, body, err = editor.EditTitleAndBody()
utils.Check(err)
```

The goal would be to directly infer `title` and `body` from the `message`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems like modifying `hub` to work this way is pretty much out of the question. See [`hub` issue #722](https://github.com/github/hub/issues/722) for more details. I came up with [a workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27275598/how-can-i-send-a-pull-request-using-hub-with-the-default-message-without-openin/27279973#answer-27279973) if anyone needs it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible (and it will likely not be possible in the future for reasons outlined in [hub issue #722](https://github.com/github/hub/issues/722#issuecomment-67916346)), but I created a workaround in case anyone else wants this feature in `hub`:

1. Create an empty shell script called something like `no-edit.sh`:

   ```
   echo '#!/bin/bash' > no-edit.sh
   chmod +x no-edit.sh
   ```

   **Note:** You can edit this script to output the message with `cat "$1"` if you want.

   **Note 2:** Alternatively you could just use `/usr/bin/true` as recommended by [mislav](https://github.com/mislav) on [`hub` github issue #722](https://github.com/github/hub/issues/722#issuecomment-67916346).
2. Create the following shell script and call it whatever you want (I went with `hub-no-edit.sh`):

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   OLD_GIT_EDITOR=$GIT_EDITOR
   export GIT_EDITOR=/path/to/no-edit.sh
   hub $@
   export GIT_EDITOR=$OLD_GIT_EDITOR
   ```
3. Now just put the second script on your path and you can execute a `pull-request` without editing the message:

   ```
   hub-no-edit.sh pull-request -b base:master -h me:feature
   ```